# Scrobble iTunes Radio

Tags: itunes, macos, itunes-radio

With the release of iOS7 and new OSX people will use iTunes Radio more and more. I've been using it for a while now and would love to be able to scrobble my songs in Last.fm.

I've done some research and found this software:
http://www.easyclasspage.de/lastfm/seite-19.html

However, it crashes and doesn't seem to work for me.

Are any alternative options to scrobble iTunes Radio available out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t use iTunes Radio, but judging from the nature of how iTunes plays music, I can safely say you can scrobble to Last.fm with [Bowtie](http://bowtieapp.com).

I don’t know if there any apps that can scrobble to Last.fm on iOS though since streaming to iTunes Radio requires the official app, which can’t be used by third party apps.